# freenx sound fw

Tags: 12.04, networking, remote-desktop, nx, freenx

How can I get sound forwarding from a 12.04 to a 12.04 ubuntu machine ?
I have tried a couple things I found on google, but none worked. There were not targetted towards ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a few months ago, but I've found a solution to this problem : it's not necessary to activate sound forwarding in nxclient, but you have to type this command within a terminal after opening nx session :
`pacmd load-module module-tunnel-sink server=[YOUR_CLIENT_IP]`.

Make sure the volume is on and high enough (this sounds stupid, but I've lost time because of that…), and this should work. I think there should be a mean to have this command run automatically on session launch, but I didn't try to do that.

Comment: [Here's how to run it at startup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/108800/run-shell-script-on-startup-or-boot)