# Running script at startup when using i3wm

Tags: startup, startup-applications, i3-wm

I can't for the life of me get scripts to run at startup.
I have a script called "startup.sh" in my home directory.  I have tried (at least) the following ways to get it to run at startup:

- Adding it to `.profile`
- Adding it to `.bashrc`
- Adding a run command to i3's config in `/etc` (I use i3)
- Adding it to Xsession and xinitrc (I think, will retry)
- Adding it to `/etc/rc.local`
- Adding it to `init.d`

The only thing that worked was Unity's **Startup Applications** menu, which doesn't work with i3.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can refer to this link:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/108800/run-shell-script-on-startup-or-boot

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo` command (just in case) without asking for password command line:

```
echo YOUR_PASSWORD | sudo -S YOUR_COMMAND
```

Put command lines in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local
```

*Imformation sources:*

[Stack Overflow: How to Run a Shell Script at Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

Answer (score 2):

Ah, found it.  I was editing `/etc/.i3/config`, which is the config for the root user.  I should have been using `/home/foo/.i3/config`.  Putting my commands in the latter solved it.

Answer (score 0):

- From **Dash** search startup applications.
  [image]
- click on add button
- click on browse button
  [image]
- select the script you want to run on startup
- give an appropriate name

Comment: I guess @adity patil `OP` clearly said "The only thing that worked was Unity's "startup applications" menu, which doesn't work with i3." So, can you define your point in writing this ^ ?