# How to start a program in startup that I start in terminal

Tags: startup, executable

I'm a beginner user and need help to have a program start on startup. The computer is solely being used for this, so I don't care about doing anything else on the computer.
To run it normally, I go to terminal and type:

```
cd src
cd SARndbox-1.5
sudo bin/SARndbox -fpv -evr -0.02
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: start up meaning booot or start up meaning when you log in ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run shell script on startup or boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/108800/run-shell-script-on-startup-or-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Search in the Dash:-

Startup application--> Open it--->  Add--> In pop--> name it and in command type-->sudo bin/SARndbox -fpv -evr -0.02

Restart

Answer (score 0):

Press the windows key, and start typing "startup application", click on the startup application.

Click on Add button.

In the command section, type the following (This is by assuming that your src directory is in the home folder)

```
cd ~/src/SARndbox-1.5 && sudo bin/SARndbox -fpv -evr -0.02
```

Click on Add, and on your next restart this will work as a start up application.