# How do I start SARndbox when Ubuntu boots

Tags: startup

I need help to make SARndbox startup when Ubuntu boots. I have been use your other solution for this problem but does not startup ([How to start a program in startup that I start in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598521/how-to-start-a-program-in-startup-that-i-start-in-terminal)).

The lines I use:

```
sudo su

(password)

cd ~/src/SARndbox-1.5-001

./bin/SARndbox -uhm -fpv
```

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash script.  Enter the following in your favorite text editor (without quotes):

"#!/bin/bash 
 cd ~/src/SARndbox-1.5-0001 
sudo ./bin/SARndbox -uhm -fpv"

Save as SARndbox.sh, or whatever you want to call it.  Make the script executable by either right-clicking it in a file browser and altering the permissions graphically, checking the box allowing it to be run as a program, or by opening a terminal in the folder where it's saved and typing:

chmod +x SARndbox.sh

Add this script to your startup applications in System Settings, and it should automatically run next restart or login.  You'll have to manually type in your password.  There is a way to save your password credentials somewhere and link to those creds from within the script, but that is beyond my ken.